# TypeScript callback type

Tags: typescript

I have a case like this:

```
function createCar(name: string, callback: () => void)

function buildEngine(name: string): Engine

function createCarWithEngine(carName: string, engineName: string, callback: (param: Engine) => void) {
  let createdEngine = createdEngines.find((engine) => engine.name === engineName)
  if (!createdEngine) createdEngine = buildEngine(engineName)

  createCar(carName, () => callback(createdEngine)) // error here
}
```

VSCode tells me `createdEngine` maybe undefined. However this is fine:

```
  const fn = callback(createdEngine)

  createCar(carname, () => fn)
```

Is this an intended behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 cases aren't equivalent.

In the second case you call `callback` inside the function, in the first you defer the call for a later time.

This will fail with the same error

```
 const fn = () => callback(createdEngine)

 createCar(carname, fn)
```

This is related to the fact that TS cannot know what happens with `createdEngine` because the function will be called later on. When you call `createEngine` inside your function then it knows that the calls are done in sync so it narrows the type down.

Interesting enough if you ensure that the type of `createdEngine` is `Engine` at all times then this will work.

```
function createCarWithEngine(carName: string, engineName: string, callback: (param: Engine) => void) {
  let createdEngine = createdEngines.find((engine) => engine.name === engineName) || buildEngine(engineName)

  createCar(carName, () => callback(createdEngine)) // error here
}
```